# How to create a matrix in r using product of all possible two column combination?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a matrix that has the product of all possible two column combinations. Suppose, matrix has 6 columns and 4 rows then my output matrix has 15 columns and 4 rows.

Answer (score 2):

The `combn` have a `FUN` option.  So, we can directly pass the function inside `combn`.  (Using @RHertel's example)

```
combn(n_col,2, FUN=function(x) x[1]*x[2])
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  6  8 10 12 12 15 18 20 24 30
```

Or instead of using the anonymous function, `prod` can be called

```
combn(n_col,2, FUN=prod)
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  6  8 10 12 12 15 18 20 24 30
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
n_col <- 6
t(as.matrix(combn(n_col,2)[1,]*combn(n_col,2)[2,]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
#[1,]    2    3    4    5    6    6    8   10   12    12    15    18    20    24    30
```

---

Or you could use the `colProds` function from the [`matrixStats`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixStats/index.html) package to multiply the columns:

```
library(matrixStats)
n_col <- 6
t(as.matrix(colProds(combn(n_col,2))))
```

Comment: @rxk011 I don't understand what the expected output would be in that case. All two-column product combinations are included in the answer. The result depends only on the number of columns, and not on the rows. Do you wish to replicate this output for each row?

Comment: @rxk011 Sorry, but I still don't understand it. In any case, the situation that you're describing appears to be quite significantly different from your original question. If the answers to the original question don't help you, I suggest that you ask a new question where you can clarify the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your original matrix is `df`

### Columns combinations

```
cols <- combn(ncol(df), 2, simplify=F, FUN=as.numeric)
```

### Get the product and prepare a output data.frame

```
cbind.data.frame(
    lapply(cols, function(x){
        apply(df[, x], 1, prod)
    })
)
```

Comment: @rxk011 It's an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions).

Comment: yes, as @rxk011 said, it is an anonymous function just made up for lapply. You can use for-loop if you like

Comment: Thank you so much.